# inner product of inner product

Tags: vector-spaces, normed-spaces, inner-products

A simple question on inner product properties:

How can I get from 
$\left \langle v,\left \langle v,e_{n} \right \rangle e_{n}      \right \rangle$
to $\left \langle v,e_{n} \right \rangle \left \langle v,e_{n} \right \rangle$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean $\left \langle v\left \langle v,e_{n} \right \rangle ,e_{n}      \right \rangle$ ?

Comment: Yes that is it! Sorry for the typo!
edit: No wait, the other way around

Comment: @CanisLupus The appropriate changes has been made.

Comment: $\left \langle v,e_{n} \right \rangle$ is a scalar.

Comment: From my workings, this reduces to $\left \langle v,v \right \rangle$  which is $\left \| v \right \|_{p=2}^{2}$ I've tried to look at the bilinear property. @CanisLupus

Comment: Assuming your inner product is linear in the second argument and conjugate-linear in the first (the physicists' convention), $\langle v,\lambda w\rangle=\lambda \langle v,w\rangle$ for all vectors $v,w$ and scalars $\lambda$.

Comment: Got it! Thanks @CanisLupus 
From $\left \langle v,e \right \rangle =\left \| v \right \|_{p=2}^{2}$ is a scalar $\alpha$, this is just $\alpha=\left \langle v,e \right \rangle$. So, the result follows

Comment: @arctictern as a slight departure from the OP, since I'm working in a Hilbert space, is the norm necessarily the $L^{p=2}$ space and the norm being the euclidean norm?

Comment: It doesn't matter what the norm is.